# Convert to LATEX

Tags: convert

I have been using [MathPix](https://mathpix.com/) snipping tool using which I can convert text, equations and other mathematics symbols to .tex without fuss. However, it does not work well with tables. Is there a better free tool that would be handy in this regard? Also, is there a way to convert a figure such as a circle or a line from a snap (.jpg) to tikz code?

Comment: For the picture: You can try opening it in Inkscape, tracing it to get a vector image, and export the result as Ti*k*Z code.

Comment: mathpix does incredibly well but it is just interpreting the image, of you have the source then you should always get more accurate text translation. So for converting tables to latex the question is what are you converting from? if you only habe an image of a table, then mathpix is your friend but of you hav ethe table as text source in any format you shpuld be able to write as latex fairly quickly